# Replace commons.io FileUtils.listFiles for nio

Tags: java, nio, directory

I need replace commons.io FileUtils.listFiles becouse is very slow to proccess bigs directories.
I read thats java nio is more fast.
My question is, how can replace this method with nio:

```
public List<File> listFiles(){
    File dir = new File(this._dir);
    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, this.get_extensions(), true);

    return files;
}
```

thanks!!

Perform the following test:

```
public List<File> listFiles(){
    File dir = new File(this._dir);
    Path dire = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( this._dir );
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(dire, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                // here you have the files to process
                if (file.toString().endsWith("IDC.xml")) {
                    System.out.println(file);

                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
               return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
              return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( "NIO: " + (stop - start) + " ms" );
     start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, this.get_extensions(), true);
     stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( "IO: " + (stop - start) + " ms" );
    return files;
}
```

The time of nio is more short than io.

---

I find the next solution:

```
public List<String> listFiles(){
    File dir = new File(this._dir);
    Path dire = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( this._dir );
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(dire, new FindTextFilesVisitor());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( "NIO: " + (stop - start) + " ms" );

    return this._lista;
}
public Boolean changeString( String str ) {
    this._lista.add(str);
    return true;
}
/**
 * FindTextFilesVisitor.
 */
public class FindTextFilesVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                     BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException {
        if (file.toString().endsWith("IDC.xml")) {
            System.out.println(file.getParent());
            changeString(file.getParent().toString());
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Becouse the FileUtils.listFiles consume a lot of time to process a big directory.

Comment: So..have you put in any effort yourself, or are you expecting us to write it for you?

Comment: Justin, i add a test in the question. My problem is how put the directory information obtain in System.out.println(file); into List<String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NIO2, you can create a stream so that not everything is kept in memory. 
So, you are probably looking to do something like this:

```
DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> pathFilter = ...
try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(directory), pathFilter)) {
    for (Path path : directoryStream) {
        ...
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Note that it is important that you don't convert the stream to a list, otherwise what would be the point, right? So, you should probably change your method signature too.

Comment: Hi! directoryStream is recursive?

Comment: Nope, but, that's a easy recursion to do.

Comment: this will be recursive?  "if (Files.isDirectory(child))" addTree(child, all);

Comment: Please, Can show me how make recursive directoryStream?

Comment: Actually, in that case, you could use ``Files.walk(Path start, FileVisitOption... options)`` which also provides you a stream